# Grails querying the database

Tags: grails

I am trying to query a database within grails using:

```
            def per = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
            def query = Post.whereAny {
                author { username == per.username }
            }.order 'dateCreated', 'desc'
            messages = query.list(max: 10)
```

My User is in a User domain and in the Post domain I have:

```
    String message
    User author
    Date dateCreated
```

when I run this query its empty every time my method in the controller for populating the database is:

```
  def updateStatus() {
         def status = new Post(message: params.message)
        System.out.println("test " + params.message)
            status.author = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
        status.save()
    }
```

I am very new at quering databases in grails so if anyone could recommend some reading this would be good too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New version of spring-security-core plugin add methods to you controller, thus you can replace:

```
def per = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
def query = Post.whereAny {
    author { username == per.username }
}.order 'dateCreated', 'desc'
messages = query.list(max: 10)
```

with

```
messages = Post.findAllByAuthor(principal, [sort: 'dateCreated', order 'desc', max: 10])
```

Without declaring springSecurityService

You can replace the updateStatus action with:

```
def updateStatus(){
    def status = new Post(message: params.message, author: principal)
    status.save()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty query may be resolved with:

```
def updateStatus() {
     def status = new Post(message: params.message)
    System.out.println("test " + params.message)
        status.author = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
    status.save(flush: true)
}
```

This may help you find the data later as the save() just gives your hibernate context the instruction to persist the data, but does not force hibernate to do it at that moment. passing flush:true will force data to be persisted immediately. Also status.save(failOnError:true) will reveal if your domain object properties have validation issues preventing the domain instance from being saved at all to the database (by throwing an Exception). You can use both if desired:

```
def updateStatus() {
     def status = new Post(message: params.message)
    System.out.println("test " + params.message)
        status.author = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
    status.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
}
```

hope that helps.

You can set flush and failOnError: true globally as well in grails-app/conf/Config.groovy:

```
grails.gorm.failOnError=true
grails.gorm.autoFlush=true
```